# com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: StructureElement shall contain parent object exception is thrown when form.flattenFields() method is called in iText

Tags: javascript, itext, pdf-generation, aem, itext7

I have a requirement where templates are generated through AEM and then iText consumes it to populate data on to those fields.

Data is mapped successfully on to the text fields in the template. After that, while trying to flatten the pdf I receive below exception

com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: StructureElement shall contain parent object.
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.tagutils.TagTreePointer.setCurrentStructElem(TagTreePointer.java:718) ~[kernel-7.1.12.jar:?]
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.tagutils.TagStructureContext.removeAnnotationTag(TagStructureContext.java:342) ~[kernel-7.1.12.jar:?]
at com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm.flattenFields(PdfAcroForm.java:658) ~[forms-7.1.12.jar:?]

The template has all text fields only and some javascript logic to hide/show some fields if empty. I removed javascript logic(iText doesnt recognize this logic anyways) and tested to see if flatten works and it didn't.

I doubt if my template generated through AEM where I am creating .pdf file from .xdp file caused this issue. I just used save as option in LiveCycle designer of AEM to create it. Any other suggestion to create accurate .pdf file so iText doesn't throw exception on flattening?

Comment: iText 7.1.12 is by far not the current iText 7. Have you tried updating your iText dependency to check whether that was an iText bug that meanwhile has been fixed?

Comment: I tried with 7.2.5 version and had same issue

Comment: OK. Can you share an example PDF to reproduce the issue?

Comment: There are errors in the structure tree of the document, some form field widgets have associated structure elements which are not in the structure tree.  iText form flattening stumbles in the attempt to properly update the structure tree when removing those widgets. If you make iText believe that the document is not tagged, it doesn't attempt that structure tree update and, consequentially, flattens the form without further ado.

Comment: I had a .pdf file(someone else created it) that was created in the past which has no issues with iText. I imported the same .pdf file to AEM designer and without making any change I just saved it again as .pdf file from designer, it fails during flattening. I suspect AEM causing some issues while creating .pdf file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that issue with Structure tags of form fields is the root cause for this. And structure tags are basically not configured correctly in AEM 6.5.15 version, whereas a .PDF file template created using AEM 6.5.11 or below has right structure tags.

Have an open ticket with Adobe to discuss this issue. Thanks